# Parameter inference using deviance in normal linear model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, deviance

I' am reading [An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584889500). The authors introduce using deviance and discuss how it can be used directly as a goodness of fit statistic in logistic regression and poisson regression because there are no nuisance parameters, but not for normal linear model because $\sigma^2$ is unknown.

Here is one quote on page 80, "If the response variables $Y_i$ are Normally distributed then $D$ has a chi-squared distribution exactly. In this case, however, $D$ depends on $var(Y_i)=\sigma^2$, which, in practice, is usually unknown. This means that $D$ cannot be used directly as a goodness of fit statistic"

Why is that the case? Why can we not just estimate $\sigma^2$ and then use deviance as a goodness of fit statistic?